# querying with projections in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have defined the following class:

```
class abc(Document)
    attrib1 = StringField()
    attrib2 = StringField()
    attrib3 = StringField()
    .
    .
    attrib30 = StringField()
```

I need to get only `attrib1, attrib2, attrib3` as json output. How can I do that projection with only 3 attributes from my document?

Here is my query which works for one attribute:

```
for cur in abc.objects(Q(attrib1='xzy') or Q(attrib2='abc')):
    print(json_util.dumps(cur.attrib1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your are wrong.

You are making a query where results needs to contain  `attrib1='xyz'` or `attrib2='abc'`, but you are returning all fields (attributes).

Before you can fix the projection, the actual query needs to be corrected to use [bitwise operators](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries) rather than `and` or `or`.

To specify only certain fields to be returned from the database you need to specify that in the [projection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find).

`abc.objects(Q(attrib1='xzy') | Q(attrib2='abc'))`

In  MongoEngine you can do that by using `only`:

```
   result = abc.objects(Q(attrib1='xzy') | Q(attrib2='abc')).only('attrib1', 'attrib2', 'attrib3')
```

In this way, `result` is a [`queryset`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet) which contain results having only those 3 fields. Than you can do what you want with hte result.

What you are doing in here:

`print(json_util.dumps(cur.attrib1))`,

is that you are accessing the `attrib1` of each document, and print it, but actually all documents still have all the fields inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
from app.models import myCollection
from mongoengine import connect
connect('MyDBName')
# Fetch the data using projection (only)
data = myCollection.objects(key1='val1', timestamp=datetime(2021, 2, 17, 13, 9, 25)).only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

# then access the data like below:
print("Data length= %d, Type= %s" %(len(data), type(data)))
print("value = ", data[0].field1)
```

Responses below:

```
Data length= 366, Type= <class 'flask_mongoengine.BaseQuerySet'>
value = field1_value
```